css horizontal dropdown menu going "behind" a section
i've created a horizontal dropdown menu in css but when i hover it the dropdown part goes "underneath" the section, so im trying to figure out how to make the dropdown menu go over section


header{
    width:80%;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#navMenu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:80%
}
#navMenu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;
}
#navMenu li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#navMenu ul li a {
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
    color:white;
}
#navMenu ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:30px;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul{
    visibility:visible;
    background-color:#333333;
}
section {
  width:80%;
  background-color:#b5b5b5;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  border-color:black;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:5px;
  padding:5px;
}
<body>
<header>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navMenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="progetto2.html">MUSIC</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</header>
<section>
</section>
</body>



im not really practical with this so i dont know what to do in order to make the dropdown menu go over section

The reason why the submenu appears to be behind the header element is because of the declaration overflow: hidden.
You can try it with the following:
header{
  display: flex;
  width:80%;
  background-color:black;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding:10px;
}

If you want the <div id="wrapper> to fill the available space, add flex: 1 to it, which is a shortcut for flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 0%;.
Note that you could also use display: grid instead, it really depends on the layout you are working on.
